# Get text from ReadOnly MSWord document

Tags: lotusscript

I can't understand, how read a MS Word documents not in a read mode. I'm trying to use a macros, but still don't understand how to apply View.ReadingLayout in my script. Debug always return for me "

> Instance member Wiew does not exist

"
Basicaly, my task is get text from MSWord. But what doing if document status "ReadOnly". And debug return, Path/file access error 75 in line 29

Thank you!

Comment: What is the code you're using to open the file?

Comment: In my case, seems like i already found solution. My mistake was that i used kill function. When i started using createobject("scripting.filesystemobject"). deletefiles(filepath) all start works well. Anyway thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Dim wrdApp As Variant
    Dim wordFile As Variant
    On Error GoTo errorhandler

```
Dim count As Integer

Set wrdApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
filepath = "E:\IBM\Temp\" & object.Source 
Call object.ExtractFile(filepath)
Set wordFile = GetObject(filepath , "Word.Document")
wordFile.Application.Visible = False
If wordFile.ProtectionType <> -1 Then
    Print "Document is protected"
Else
    count = wordFile.Paragraphs.Count
    wordFile.Paragraphs(1).Range.Select
    rttext = wordFile.content.text  
End If
Call wordFile.Application.Quit()
Set wrdApp = Nothing 
createobject("scripting.filesystemobject").deletefile(filepath)
```

Comment: Huh. Thanks for posting this! I'd never used FileSystemObject before and it looks very useful. If you have any thoughts on why that worked but `Kill` doesn't, please let me know.